# Como esconder a linha vertical mostrada no editor do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

No editor de códigos do Android Studio 3.0 é exibida uma linha vertical na posição 88, tanto para arquivos **.java** quanto para arquivos **.xml**.

A imagem abaixo exibe exatamente o que acabei de descrever:

[image: Editor de textos com a linha vertical sendo exibida]

Como faço para esconder esta linha?

Procurei nas configurações [ <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd> ] e não encontrei opção que me satisfaça.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esconder ou mostrar a linha aceda a:

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show right margin

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]